# socket io to much rerendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, react-hooks, socket.io-1.0

I'm using socketio and react. Im trying to set state for all users when one use changes it but it causes too much rerendering on site.

server.js

```
const app = require('express')

const http = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
    cors: {
       origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    },
  });

let subject = ''

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('setSubject', (sbj) => {
        subject = sbj
        io.sockets.emit('getSubject',subject)
    })
    socket.on('changeHiddenPassword',hiddenPassword => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('newHiddenPassword',hiddenPassword)
    })
    
})

http.listen(4001,function(){
    console.log('listening on port 4001')
})
```

front end

```
const [hiddenPassword,changeHiddenPassword] = useState([''])

useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit('changeHiddenPassword',hiddenPassword)
    }, [hiddenPassword]);
    
      socket.on('newHiddenPassword',newHiddenPassword => {
          changeHiddenPassword(newHiddenPassword)
        })
```

I dont think rest of the code will help you somehow but if it would i can provide it to you. What i'm trying to do is when someone clicks on specific element on my site i want my hiddenPasword state to change for all connected users. I know that what i'm doing is wrong,beacouse when the state changes for one user useEffect is passing and setting state to everyone else and  their useEffect are passing and setting state to everyone else and so on... I want to know how to do it properly and i cant figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

so when you change `hiddenPassword` you are emitting `changeHiddenPassword` event, this sends back `newHiddenPassword` event which changes the `hiddenPassword` and this continues infinitely.

Try modifying `newHiddenPassword` handler like this, so it's not changing the state (and triggering useEffect) when the received password is already up to date

```
 socket.on('newHiddenPassword',newHiddenPassword => {
     if (newHiddenPassword !== hiddenPassword) {
         changeHiddenPassword(newHiddenPassword);
     }
 });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention i tried this method before and it didnt work.

Comment: ok, another thing that comes to my mind is that you define a handler whenever component is rerendered, because `socket.on('newHiddenPassword'...` is defined directly in component functions's body. Could you try using `socket.off('newHiddenPassword')` just before you define the handler to remove all already existing ones?